# Purpose of %%GLOBAL_HeadFonts%% in Bigcommerce templates?

Tags: templates, bigcommerce

Noticed the template variable `%%GLOBAL_HeadFonts%%` in *HTMLHead.html* in the Bigcommerce Blueprint theme as well as other themes.

What I don't understand is where the value of this variable can be set in the Bigcommerce admin interface / back-end.  I notice that theme authors seem to stick additional fonts directly into *HTMLHead.html* before/after `%%GLOBAL_HeadFonts%%`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%%GLOBAL_HeadFonts%%` is used to fetch the base theme's fonts. Since you have no control over any `%%GLOBAL.something%%` and `%%LNG.something%%` its better to call your fonts just under this line. You can upload your fonts by creating a fonts directory (under template) then call those fonts either within your Style.css or externally using `%%ASSET.fonts/myfont.wof%%`

Use this https://developer.bigcommerce.com/themes/panels/html_head to understand BigCommerce HTML.head architecture.

Comment: Great explanation - thanks. I didn't realise you could do something like %%ASSET.xxxx/yyy.zzz%% to load assets using the BC template language.